# sending HTML-form with ajax and jQuery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make first steps with JavaScript using the jQuery-library and Ajax. I  want to read a HTML-form and recieve the users input in a PHP file. The following is a JavaScript function to sends the form via Ajax to the webserver:

```
function get_post( ) {

    $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : "ajax.php",
        data : $("form").serialize(),
        cache : false,
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );

        }
    });
```

};

In the console.log the right input data are shown and also with the PHP-debug-output, which is programmed in ajax.php. 
console.log(data) gives:

> Parameter: temperature
> Sensorknoten: Node1
> Start: 2017-04-20 14:15
> End: 2017-04-06 06:30

which is obviously correct.

*Echo*ing the PHP-variables in the Browser gives:

> Parameter: FIELD EMPTY
>   Sensorknoten: FIELD EMPTY
>   Start: FIELD EMPTY
>   End: FIELD EMPTY

ajax.php  calls a class named UsersInput, which should retrieves the userinput with the gloabal $_POST. The different $_POST-methods in UserInput are similair to this

```
public function getNodes() {
    $location = isset($_POST['location'])?$_POST['location']:"FIELD EMPTY";
    return $location;
}
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/autoload.php';


/*
 * get users input from HTML-Form 
 * @param object: $userIn
 */

$userIn = new UserInput();
$param = $userIn->getParams();
$node = $userIn->getNodes();
$start = $userIn->getStartdate();
$end = $userIn->getEnddate();
//debug output
echo "Parameter: $param";
echo"<br />";
echo "Sensorknoten: $node";
echo"<br />";
echo "Start: $start";
echo"<br />";
echo "End: $end";
echo"<br />";   
?>
```

This is the HTML-form:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="nodeformsend" value="true">
<!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Welcome!
            <small>Now, you are able to visualize your Data</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.html">Sensor Monitoring</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">Visualize Data</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- table to select different Nodes -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Select Wireless Sensor Sodes</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <select class="form-control" id="location" name="location">
                <?php for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) : ?>
                        <option  name="location[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="Node<?php echo $i ?>">Wireless Senssor Node <?php echo $i ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- table to select different parameters -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Select Parameteres</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <select class="form-control" id="parameter" name="parameter">
                    <option  name="parameter[0]" value="temperature">Temperature</option>
                    <option  name="parameter[1]" value="humidity">Humidity</option>
                    <option  name="parameter[2]" value="pressure">Pressure</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Begin of Timestamp</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetime-start" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" >                                           
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" name="datetime-start" type="text" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- table to select Timestamps-->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">End of Timestamp</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetime-end" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" >                                         
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" name="datetime-end" type="text" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="get_post();">
```

**EDIT**

Yes, of course! Here it is:

```
<?php
//__________This class parse the usersinput UI__________

class UserInput{
    /**
     * get Nodes from UsersInput
     * $location = Node[i]
     */
    public function getNodes() {
        $location ='';
        $location = isset($_POST['location'])?$_POST['location']:"FIELD EMPTY";                                         //load the inputs of user to a variable as an array
        return $location;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     * $parameter = Temperature, Humidty, Pressure 
     */
    public function getParams() {
        $parameter = isset($_POST['parameter'])?$_POST['parameter']:"FIELD EMPTY";
        return $parameter;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     * $start = 'YYYY-mm-DD hh:ii:ss < $end
     */
    public function getStartdate() {
        $start = isset($_POST['datetime-start'])?$_POST['datetime-start']:"FIELD EMPTY";
        return $start;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     * $end = 'YYYY-mm-DD hh:ii:ss
     */
    public function getEnddate() {
        $end = isset($_POST['datetime-end'])?$_POST['datetime-end']:"FIELD EMPTY";
        return $end;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     */
}
```

Comment: I think that when you call the functions on the UserInput object the global $_POST variable is no more the same bacause you call it in another file. I would pass the $_POST variable to the function like this: `$param = $userIn->getParams($_POST);`

Comment: parse the $_POST as a parameter and do not access as a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the $_POST as a parameter and not a global variable. The value of the $_POST has changed. Alternatively since you have a class, you can take advantage of Object oriented programming: Now we add a construct function and when instantiating the class, we pass the `$_POST` as a parameter. This way we do not have to worry about accessing from `$_POST`

Also if you are going to save these details to your database, please properly sanitize the input strings

```
$userIn = new UserInput($_POST);
$param = $userIn->getParams();
$node = $userIn->getNodes();
$start = $userIn->getStartdate();
$end = $userIn->getEnddate();
```

And in your class

```
<?php
//__________This class parse the usersinput UI__________

class UserInput{

  var $variables = array();     

   public function __construct($posted_variables){
    try{
     if(is_array($posted_variables) && isset($posted_variables)){
        $this->variables = $posted_variables; 
      }else{
         throw new Exception('Post is empty'.var_dump($variables));
      }
    }catch(Exception $ex){
      echo $ex->getTraceAsString();
   } 
  }

    /**
     * get Nodes from UsersInput
     * $location = Node[i]
     */
    public function getNodes() {
        $location ='';
        $location = isset($this->variables['location'])?$this->variables['location']:"FIELD EMPTY";                                         //load the inputs of user to a variable as an array
        return $location;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     * $parameter = Temperature, Humidty, Pressure 
     */
    public function getParams() {
     //example:
        $parameter = isset($this->variables['parameter'])?$this->variables['parameter']:"FIELD EMPTY";
        return $parameter;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     * $start = 'YYYY-mm-DD hh:ii:ss < $end
     */
    public function getStartdate() {
        $start = isset($this->variables['datetime-start'])?$this->variables['datetime-start']:"FIELD EMPTY";
        return $start;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     * $end = 'YYYY-mm-DD hh:ii:ss
     */
    public function getEnddate() {
        $end = isset($this->variables['datetime-end'])?$this->variables['datetime-end']:"FIELD EMPTY";
        return $end;
    }
    /**
     * get Nodes from UI
     */
}
```

Comment: What should I do with the global $_POST in the UserInput-class?

Comment: check my answer. I have updated your class. You do not need to use global

Comment: Pleasure! Happy coding

Comment: Excuse me, I thought it works now, but it doesnt. Again the variables are shown with "FIELD EMPTY" on the Webpage, in the JSconsole they have the correct values. 

I debuged the code by print_r($posted_variables) after the allocation by variables in __constructer. The JSconsole shows an array with the correct values, but on the webpage print_r($posted_variables) gives "Array()". I think there must be something wrong with the  dataformat, which prevents the PHP-interpreter reading the values.